# trouble with apply statement in R

Tags: r, apply

I want to use an apply statement to do something to each row of a data frame in R.

The following works where I call the function "calc.Sphere.Metrics" with a bunch of parameters and an index i. I store the result in each row.

```
for(i in 1: dim(position.matrix)[1]){
   results.obs[i,] <- calc.Sphere.Metrics(i, culled.mutation.data, position.matrix, protein.metrics, radius) 
 }
```

I've tried several apply, mapply statements but am having no luck. What would be the correct way to do this?

EDIT:
As requested, here's a skeleton of calc.Sphere.Metrics

```
calc.Sphere.Metrics <- function(index, culled.mutation.data, position.matrix, protein.metrics, radius){
  results <- matrix(data = 0, nrow = 1, ncol = 8)
  colnames(results) <- c("Line.Length","Center", "Start","End","Positions","MutsCount","P.Value", "Within.Range")
  results <- as.data.frame(results)

 ....
 look up a bunch of stuff and fill in each column of results. All the data required is in the parameters passed in and the index.  
 .....
 return(results)
}
```

Results has the same number of columns as results.obs in the top function. Hope this helps!

Thanks!

Comment: We will probably need more detail in order to help. The full contents of `calc.Sphere.Metrics` for starters, probably.

Comment: calc shere metrics is a bit confusing but what it does is takes the index i, looks up specific values in the other parameters such as mutation.data, position.matrix, etc, and returns a data frame results of 1 row and 8 columns (the exact same as results.obs).

Comment: Why just a skeleton? Is it really too long? We're asking in hope that everything can be vectorized.

Comment: Matthew's answer will probably work as a direct replacement for your `for` loop. But I asked for more code because writing functions that pull whole objects from the calling environments when the intent is to operate on them iteratively is often a sign that something bad is happening in that function.

Comment: I don't need to do it iteratively. Every row is "independent" so to speak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
result.obs <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_len(dim(position_matrix)[1]),
    calc.Sphere.Metrics, culled.mutation.data, position.matrix, protein.metrics, radius))
```

Comment: this is close, but because calc.Sphere.Metrics returns a data frame with 1 row and 8 columns, the resulting list that is created is not clear. Each return from calc.Sphere.Metrics is correctly formatted though.

Comment: In the end, this worked. You set me on the right path though, thanks!
      as.data.frame(t(sapply(seq(position.matrix[,2]), calc.Sphere.Metrics, culled.mutation.data, position.matrix, protein.metrics, radius)))